# Is it ok to post a feature-request someone else came up with in a comment or chat

Tags: discussion

... but didn't post himself? Should I mark it CW at least then since the rep shouldn't be mine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd first leave a comment on the original post suggesting that they should post the idea themselves.  If they decline, feel free to post it yourself.  I don't think you need to make it CW, since you're the one making the effort to post the suggestion.  It won't do any harm to give a citation in the form of a link to the original post, just so people can see how the idea came about.

Comment: so [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57030/option-to-star-a-conversation-that-is-listed-on-right-will-make-staring-a-message) is ok?

Comment: @Tob, it would if it was understandable

Comment: @Juan Manuel: I tried to clarify a bit... did you use the chat already?

Comment: @Tob, I have, that doesn't make me understand that phrase any better. Furthermore, the chat will close in 3 days, making the link in the question a dead link. I suggest you write the full suggestion in the post.

Comment: @Tobias: I agree with @Juan.  That request isn't entirely clear.  I didn't realize you were talking about a suggestion from chat.  It would be better to flesh out the suggestion in full.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard♦ & @Juan Manuel: You're right, I hope I put some more visible effort into it now

Answer (score 1):

Yes. An idea is an idea, and if it's interesting, it is a good contribution to the site regardless of its origin.

> Should I mark it CW at least then
>   since the rep shouldn't be mine?

I don't think it should be CW just because of that. Use it if you want to encourage collaborative editing.